# Echo the Final URL of an HTTPS Redirect

Tags: php, curl

I need a PHP script using any library or function to grab and echo (Or save to the server) the final URL of an HTTPS redirect.

I am on shared server so I just edited the php.ini to turn on OpenSSL but can't restart the server but support team told its already working.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `curl` command.

`curl -LI <url> | grep Location` may print out what you need.

with `-L/--location` option curl will redo the request if the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location.

with `-I/--head` option curl will fetch only the HTTP-headers which may contain **Location** fields.

for full reference please check out [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the url (more precisely; the page) via

```
basename(__FILE__);
```

And you can store it into a global variable or a session, then being to do whatever you want with it(for example: storing it into the database).

```
$GLOBALS['currentFile'] = basename(__FILE__);
```

Or

```
$_SESSION['currentFile'] = basename(__FILE__);
```

And It's easy too prepend something in front of it if you want.

I hope I'm not miss-understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I couldn't quite get you. I want to input an HTTPS authenticated URL which after authentication produces a variable. I want to grab the redirected URL (final URL) and save it in a file. I suppose I can get the URL from the header but don't know how to achieve that.